# Normalization dataBase 4NF VS BCNF

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I have a database of politican, this is the RM, the keys are in bold:

Politician( **Pname**, Party, Address)

Mayor(Cellphone, Website, **Pmname**, **Fogname**)

Governor( Budget, Nickname, **Pgname**, **GoSname**)

State ( **Sname**, Population,**SoPname**)

City( **Cname**, **Sname**, population ,mname)

after BCNF I get this

Politician( **Pname**, Party, Address)

Mayor (**Pmname**, Cellphone, Website)

Friends (**Pmname**, **Fogname**)

Governor ( Budget, Nickname, **Pgname**, **GoSname**)

State (**Sname**, Population)

LiveIn (**Sname**, **SoPname**)

City( **Cname**, **Sname**, population ,Pmname)

Now I need to do the 4NF- 4 normal form...whats the difference between this both?

How can I find which table are not in 4NF?

Comment: what is SoPname? Did you derive the BCNF or was that given in the question?

Comment: I derive it..SoPname its the name of politican which live in this state..the BCNF is right I checked that, Just what the difference between 4 and BCNF? and how find which table not in 4nf?

Comment: To get to BCNF we only need to know functional dependencies, for 4NF we need to know the multi-valued dependencies too. These cannot be derived from looking at your "Relational Model" and "keys". Sorry...